# Converting a binary type SID to System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, binary, sid

I found a link on this website which shows how to convert a SID to the binary type.  Can someone please tell me how to do the reverse - to convert a binary type back to a SID.

This is the script that was provided to go from SID to binary:

```
PS> $sid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ("S-1-5-21-105005785-2143699225-541720777-501") 
PS> $c = New-Object 'byte[]' $sid.BinaryLength 
PS> $sid.GetBinaryForm($c, 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do the same in C# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258680/12508260

Comment: If you want to do the same in C# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258680/12508260

Answer (score 4):

To go from byte array to SID, try:

```
(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($c, 0)).toString()
```

Comment: You can also just use the .Value property on the resultant object instead of calling tostring(). just FYI

Comment: Great stuff; as an aside: it looks like you're trying to use _method_ syntax here, which just _happens_ to work (PowerShell parses `($c, 0)` as separate argument `@($, 0)`, which maps onto `-ArgumentList`) ; perhaps a better form is `New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $bytes, 0` or, to be explicit, `New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList @($bytes, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same in C# then you can do something like this (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258680/12508260):

In my case, the byte[] came from a ManagementEventWatcher:

```
ManagementBaseObject ne = e.NewEvent;
var securityIdentifier = System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier((byte[])ne.Properties["SID"].Value, 0);
```

You can just use securityIdentifier.ToString() to get the SID as a string.