# Convert SID string format to bytes array

Tags: c#, .net, sid

I want to convert SID string format to bytes array representation which in turn will be supplied to `LookupAccountSid()` method's second argument in C#. But I don't find any particular in built function which can do this. For example:

> SID = S-1-5-32-544

can be converted into:

> (SID: 1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0)

I saw it in some posts. but how?
Is there a easy way to achieve this? Basically I want the byte array representation of the `NT Authority\NetworkService` which is `SID = S-1-5-20`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `LookupAccountSid()` your code, or a built in function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use [`SecurityIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.aspx) object from `System.Security.Principal` namespace:

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544");
byte[] bytes = new byte[sid.BinaryLength];
sid.GetBinaryForm(bytes, 0);
```

and if you want it as a text, you can then:

```
string strsid = string.Format("(SID: {0})", string.Join(",", bytes ));
```

which produces exactly:

> (SID: 1,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,32,0,0,0,32,2,0,0)

Moreover, if you want SID of `NT Authority\NetworkService`, you can replace first line with:

```
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NetworkServiceSid, null);
```

Comment: Had all but initializing the byte[]

Comment: This code works only on Windows, though :-(

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, if you want to go the other way (byte[] to SID) it's this. In my case, the byte[] came from a ManagementEventWatcher:

```
ManagementBaseObject ne = e.NewEvent;
var securityIdentifier = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier((byte[])ne.Properties["SID"].Value, 0);
```

You can just use `securityIdentifier.ToString()` to get the SID as a string.